# How do i set the back button x position from the starting point of device position?

Tags: ios, swift

How do i set the back button x position from the starting point of device position ?

```
static func backButton(navigationItem: UINavigationItem) {
        //Back Button
        let btnBack = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 22))
        btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named:"icn-back"), for: .normal)
        btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NavBar.backBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
        let leftBtn = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: btnBack)
        leftBtn.tintColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 104/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 1)
        navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftBtn, animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: Add some more information, question is unclear

Comment: What does the X meant?

Comment: Write like this :        let btnBack = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: yourXValue, y: 0, width: 40, height: 22))

Comment: x is the origin point

Answer (score 0):

```
let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: desiredXValue, y: 0, width: 90, height: 21))
let leftButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 10))
leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Group.png"), for: UIControlState())
leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.action(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
leftButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
leftView.addSubview(leftButton)
leftView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftButton)
self.navItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```